# Use chain rule to find expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y,z,t)$, $x(t)$, $y(x,t,s)$, $z(y,x)$

So differentiating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

then differentiating y and z with respect to $t$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}[\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}]+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}[\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}[\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}}]]+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure. Usually when I've seen questions like this it's something like $f(x(t),y(t))$ so I wasn't sure what to do when $t$ is a component of the function.

Comment: For the partial wrt z there are more terms as y and x bear dependence on t.

Comment: @Rafa Budría Ah I fixed it.

Comment: Still a plus sign into the derivative for $z$ and you are done :)